# Does running HuggingFace Transformers with different sequence length on TPU causes XLA re-compilation every time?

Tags: pytorch, huggingface-transformers, tpu

Would running the running HuggingFace Transformers with different sequence length on TPU cause new computation graph to be made each time ? And thus causing XLA re-compilation every time ?

Also, while training , does that mean all batches should be padded to the over-all maximum length in the entire dataset ? If I use [the trainer](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/master/src/transformers/trainer.py), will it do it automatically for me ?

Or does the ParallelLoader of PyTorch/XLA do it ?

Answer (score 0):

The tokenizer should already be padding to a fixed max length and thus already be taking care of padding to a fixed length. But yes, it should already be handled for you. But if you did have varying lengths and shapes, indeed it would cause continuous compilations and thus training performance would be pretty bad.